# Aggregate functions (MAX, etc.) return NULL instead of no rows

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, aggregate-functions

How do I make an aggregate function (for example, `MAX`) return no rows instead of `NULL` when no rows match the given criteria?

For example, the following query returns one row:

```
SELECT MAX(salary)
FROM hr.employees
WHERE department_id = '11111'
```

Using `GROUP BY ()` doesn't help:

```
SELECT MAX(salary)
FROM hr.employees
WHERE department_id = '11111'
GROUP BY ()
```

How do I make it return no rows (0 rows selected, `NO_DATA_FOUND`)?

I am using Oracle Database 12c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `having` clause:

```
SELECT MAX(salary)
FROM hr.employees
WHERE department_id = '11111'
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0;
```

Note that `department_id` looks like a number.  If so, the comparison should be to a number -- i.e. drop the single quotes around `11111`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `MINUS`:

```sql
SELECT MAX(salary)
FROM hr.employees
WHERE department_id = '11111'
MINUS
SELECT NULL FROM DUAL;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7d5ed6beb5c47a478fd6c8f79cd8de89)*

Answer (score -2):

SELECT NVL(MAX(salary),0)
FROM hr.employees
WHERE department_id = '11111'

This would return as 0 value and then you can perform further operation, Hope that help.

Comment: The question is "How do I make it return 0 rows?" This returns a row with 0 in it rather than returning 0 rows.